# Azure Devops - Historical Agent Pool data ( Last 30 Days)

Tags: azure, azure-devops

ON Azure Devops Service we have the below feature
[Historical graph for agent pool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmZdt.png)

We are using Azure Devops 2020 and are trying to find a way to retrieve similar data using API's/ or any means available.

WE intend to create a pool consumption graph like in the below image with hour by hour availability for last 30 days.
[Pool consumption graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vibzl.png)

Can someone please guide, how to fetch this data using any means available? TIA!

Answer (score 0):

The pool consumption report uses the [Azure DevOps Analytics service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/what-is-analytics?view=azure-devops) and the `TaskAgentRequestSnapshots` endpoint.

In Azure DevOps Server 2020, you could try this API:

```
GET https://{servername}:{port}/tfs/{OrganizationName}/{ProjectName}/_odata/v4.0-preview/TaskAgentRequestSnapshots
```

Comment: tried that.. but m getting this error - {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Resource not found for the segment 'TaskAgentRequestSnapshots'.","typeName":"Microsoft.OData.UriParser.ODataUnrecognizedPathException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.OData.Core","typeKey":"ODataUnrecognizedPathException","errorCode":0,"eventId":0}